Can someone figure this out why this is not working in windows 10? it works well in windows 11
I just found some code here. I love the idea of the display (UI) and have been using it to make some compiled fixer for my organization's daily operation.
Here is the full code:
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" equ "newCmd" goto newCmd

rem Multi-line menu with options selection via DOSKEY
rem Antonio Perez Ayala
rem Set title for AppActivate
title Select option
rem Define the options
set numOpts=0

for %%a in ("Calculator=calc" "Notepad=notepad" "Paint=mspaint" "Explorer=explorer") do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set /A numOpts+=1
      set "option[!numOpts!]=%%b"
      set "app[%%b]=%%c"
   )
)

set /A numOpts+=1
set "option[!numOpts!]=Quit"
rem Options selection loop
:nextOpt

cmd /C "%~F0" newCmd
if errorlevel 1 goto nextOpt

goto :EOF

:newCmd

rem Clear previous doskey history
doskey /REINSTALL
rem Fill doskey history with menu options
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0" %numOpts%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%numOpts%) do set /P "="

cls

echo MULTI-LINE MENU WITH OPTIONS SELECTION

echo/
rem Send a F7 key to open the selection menu
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0"
rem Read the option
set /P "option=Select the desired option: "

echo/

set "continue=1"
if defined app[%option%] (
   start !app[%option%]!
) else (
   set "continue=0"
)

exit %continue%

@end

var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    envVar = wshShell.Environment("Process");

// Select the cmd.exe window
wshShell.AppActivate("Select option");

WScript.Sleep(300);

if ( WScript.Arguments.Length ) {
   // Send menu options to fill the menu
   var numOpts = parseInt(WScript.Arguments(0));
   for ( var i=1; i <= numOpts; i++ ) {
      wshShell.SendKeys(envVar("option["+i+"]")+"{ENTER}");
   }
} else {
   // Send a F7 to open the menu
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
}


How is this related to Javascript?

sorry for my post i cant make it more readable. cant arrange it well here. and btw this is a Multi-line menu with options selection via DOSKEY

the last portion of the code is from js. after @end

'this is not working in windows 10` is not an acceptable code or programming problem description. We expect your debugging information, and focused observations.

yeah i understand. thanks for clarifying that to me @Compo. maybe i just wait for my organization to upgrade our clients to w11 so that i can use this.

Antonio will probably chime in.  I believe he is still active on SO.

I tried it on Windows 10 and sometimes it worked and sometimes it did not but:
If you manually press F7 the menu always comes up. So I doubled/tripled the key press to increase the success rate:
...
else {
   // Send a F7 to open the menu
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
}

Probably not the ideal solution but it works.
